# How do you get a python array output using javascript to display on Phonegap HTML?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, phonegap

I have a function that returns the 5 most similar sentences based on a given query. How do I pass this output using javascript so that I can display it on my HTML?

I am using Phonegap, so I am unable to use Jinja which would have been easier.

Python:

```
def sentence_generator():
mytext = []
if request.method == "POST":
    data = request.get_json()
    sentences = data['list']
    key = data['key']

    line3 = sentences.split(',')
    for r in line3:
        documents.append(r.lower())
    print(documents)

    sen = sentences.replace(",", " ")
    for i in sent_tokenize(sen):
        temp = []

        for j in word_tokenize(i):
            temp.append(j.lower())
        wmd_corpus.append(temp)

    print(wmd_corpus)
    print(key)

    model = Word2Vec(w2v_corpus, workers=1, size=128)
    num_best = 5
    instance = WmdSimilarity(wmd_corpus, model, num_best=5)

    sent = ' '.join(key)
    query = preprocess(sent)
    sims = instance[query]  # A query is simply a "look-up" in the similarity class.
    print(sims)
    print ('Query:')
    print (query)
    for i in range(num_best):
        print ('sim = %.4f' % sims[i][1])
        print (documents[sims[i][0]])
        texts = documents[sims[i][0]]
    mytext.append(texts)
    return jsonify ({'mytext': mytext})
if request.method == "GET":
    return jsonify ({'mytext': mytext})
```

Javascript:

```
 $.getJSON("https://picatalk-api.herokuapp.com/get_sentences",function(data){
        console.log(data)
    document.getElementById('display').value = data
     }
)
```

Comment: It seems you are getting json from the server but not parsing it in the client, just displaying it as a string. What is the result you are getting now and what is the expected result?

Comment: i am getting an internal server error on my GET method

Comment: Then maybe the python side is the one not working. Do you have logs with the actual error message?

Comment: TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed it was a `GET` method, but you have an `if` checking if it is a `POST`. Either switch the request to be a `POST` or remove the `if method is GET` condition.

Comment: @solarc already mentioned about the request handling. `$.getJSON` is making a `GET` request in the route. But your route is only handling `POST` request. Moreover, in `sentence_generator` you are reading JSON value from the request `data = request.get_json()`.

Comment: oh yeah, i added the switch to if method is GET. i am able to pass the array but it is only the empty array. how do i pass the one with the data in it? i have updated the code in question.

Comment: @yuyu you are still only running the code if it is a `POST`. See the 3rd line of your python function.

Comment: @solarc i am using both POST and GET methods, one for querying and one for retrieving the results.

Comment: Only when you are sending a POST request it is running the code that starts in `data = request.get_json()`. When you send a GET it returns the empty array defined at the top.

Comment: okay, so how do i retrieve the array that has the data in it?